# SSL pinning - setting pinned public keys instead of pinned certificates in AFSecurityPolicy

Tags: ios, objective-c, ssl, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I am doing SSL pinning using AFNetworking. I got it working with the following code.

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.securityPolicy = [AFSecurityPolicy policyWithPinningMode:AFSSLPinningModePublicKey];
[manager.securityPolicy setPinnedCertificates:myCertificate];
```

My question is, is there a way to set public keys, instead of certificates, in AFSecurityPolicy? Our certificates change once in a while, and I don't want to pass that in. There is no setPublicKeys method in AFSecurityPolicy.h. The AFSecurityPolicy.m has a property `pinnedPublicKeys` but it can't be set because it's not in the header file.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The keys are extracted from the certificates either automatically with `.cer` files in your bundle, or when you set the `pinnedCertificates` property manually. Newer certs will work even if the old ones have expired, as long as the public key is unchanged.

See [the implementation of `setPinnedCertificates:`](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/3e631b203dd95bb82dfbcc2c47a2d84b59d1eeb4/AFNetworking/AFSecurityPolicy.m#L206) (and also the `AFPublicKeyForCertificate` function). I recommend setting a breakpoint and stepping through it at app launch if you're not clear how it works.

Comment: That makes sense, I did see that all AFSecurityPolicy does with my certificate is to extract my public keys, in reality I can even create a dummy certificate with the right public keys.